# How to copy file metadata on Linux and Windows from and to any filesystem that is supported by std::fs?

Tags: file, rust, copy, metadata

I need to copy a file from a given source to a given destination, not just the file content, but its metadata as well. In particular, I need to be sure that the copy will have the same modified time as the source.

To copy a file I use the function [`std::fs::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.copy.html). Its  documentation doesn't specify if the metadata is copied or not, and it fails in rare cases in copying the file metadata.

The following code:

```
fs::copy(source, dest)?;
debug_assert_eq!(
    fs::metadata(source)?.modified()?,
    fs::metadata(dest)?.modified()?
);
```

sometimes panics:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `SystemTime { tv_sec: 1556721917, tv_nsec: 270615000 }`,
 right: `SystemTime { tv_sec: 1556721917, tv_nsec: 0 }`',
```

When this fails the `tv_nsec` field is always set to 0.
Is this a bug of `std::fs::copy`? How can I copy the file metadata too?

Comment: or copy the timestamps use `utimensat`?

Comment: What operating system are you testing on and which filesystem is used for the source and destination paths?

Comment: @michalsrb Linux and Windows, any filesystem that is currently supported by `std::fs`.

Comment: @Nick Ok, but is it happening on all of them?

Comment: @michalsrb In my case I can see it happening on Linux.

Comment: @Nick My point is that different filesystems have different precision of timestamps. For example xfs and ext3 have second precision while ext4 has milisecond precision. So copying from ext4 to ext3 would cause this, but it would not be Rust's fault.

Answer (score -4):

You must call [`sync_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_all).

> Attempts to sync all OS-internal metadata to disk.
>
> This function will attempt to ensure that all in-memory data reaches the filesystem before returning.
>
> This can be used to handle errors that would otherwise only be caught when the File is closed. Dropping a file will ignore errors in synchronizing this in-memory data.

Comment: How would you use that method to ensure that the destination file has the same modified time of the source?

Comment: @Nick I only answer "When this fails the tv_nsec field is always set to 0. Is this a bug of std::fs::copy" that the problem when you ask more than one question in one question. Copy metadata doesn't interest me, you seem to have found a solution already.